# How do I create a backup of a remote Redis instance?

Tags: redis, backup

I'd like to make a backup of the data in a remote Redis instance.
But I do not have SSH access to the server that the Redis instance lives on. (Otherwise, I could copy out the `.aof` or `.rdb`-file)

How do I create a backup in this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `--rdb <filename>` argument to the `redis-cli` command-line tool:

```
redis-cli -u 'redis://<username>:<password>@<hostname>:<port>' --rdb your_backup.rdb
```

**Reference**: https://redis.io/topics/rediscli#remote-backups-of-rdb-files

Comment: Sounds great! So will this have big disadvantages, say, causing a lot of nework traffics?